# How to get a bean dynamically using Custom Qualifier Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

We're using Custom Qualifier Annotations to create and inject beans. How can we select a bean dynamically at runtime by just specifying the Custom Qualifiers.

Custom Qualifier :

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE,
        ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface PlatformQualifiers {

    public static enum OperatingSystems {
        IOS, ANDROID
    }

    OperatingSystems operatingSystem() default OperatingSystems.IOS;

    public enum DeviceTypes {
        Mobile, Tablet, ANY, Other
    }

    DeviceTypes[] deviceType() default { DeviceTypes.ANY };
}
```

Bean Interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Platform {

    String getDeviceDetails();
}
```

Bean Configs :

```
@Configuration
public class PlatformConfig {

    @Bean
    @PlatformQualifiers(operatingSystem = OperatingSystems.IOS, deviceType = DeviceTypes.Mobile)
    public Platform getIphone6() {
        return () -> "iphone6";
    }

    @Bean
    @PlatformQualifiers(operatingSystem = OperatingSystems.IOS, deviceType = DeviceTypes.Tablet)
    public Platform getIpad() {
        return () -> "ipad3";

    }

    @Bean
    @PlatformQualifiers(operatingSystem = OperatingSystems.ANDROID, deviceType = DeviceTypes.Mobile)
    public Platform getAndroidPhone() {
        return () -> "AndroidPhoneSamsung";
    }

}
```

Current Application Code :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    @PlatformQualifiers(operatingSystem = OperatingSystems.IOS, deviceType = DeviceTypes.Mobile)
    Platform iphone;


    @Autowired
    @PlatformQualifiers(operatingSystem = OperatingSystems.ANDROID, deviceType = DeviceTypes.Mobile)
    Platform androidPhone;

    public  void getDevice(String osType, String deviceType ) {
        if(osType == "ios" && deviceType == "mobile") {
            System.out.println(iphone.getDeviceDetails());
        }

        if(osType == "android" && deviceType == "mobile") {
            System.out.println(androidPhone.getDeviceDetails());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainApplication.class);
        MainApplication mainApplication = context.getBean(MainApplication.class);
        mainApplication.getDevice("ios" ,"mobile");
        mainApplication.getDevice("android" , "mobile");


    }

}
```

I am looking for a solution like where on runtime I can access bean using the qualifiers, something like this :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MainApplication2 {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public  void getDevice(DeviceTypes deviceType, OperatingSystems osType ) {
           >>>>>>>>>>> Looking of something of type following : 
            Platform p =    context.getBean(some input consisting to identify bean by  deviceType and osType)


            System.out.println(p.getDeviceDetails());
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainApplication2.class);
        MainApplication2 application = context.getBean(MainApplication2.class);
        application.getDevice(DeviceTypes.Mobile, OperatingSystems.ANDROID);
    }
}
```

In this case, How can I get a bean from applicationContext on runtime based on the DeviceTypes and OperatingSystems ?

Comment: Four years later there is still no solution that comes close to the elegance of CDI... Incredible

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches could be to create a `Map` of `Platform` beans and inject it into the bean which calls `getDevice`. The key for the map could be device type.

Another approach along the same lines could be to make your bean implement `InitializingBean` and `ApplicationContextAware` and use 'getBeansWithAnnotation' in 'afterPropertiesSet`in conjuction with`findAnnotationOnBean` to populate the Map or lookup the bean dynamically.